# Raphael random order of objects to show

Tags: javascript, raphael

Using `r.set()` I've created a collection that holds all my objects that I would like to animate.

```
var r = Raphael("holder", '100%', '100%'),
    targets = r.set(),
    size = 30,
    offset = 10;

for (var i = 0, j = 0; j < 10; i += size, j++) {
    targets.push(r.rect(i, 10, size, size));
    i += offset;
}
```

I would like to show all objects in random order using simple animate:

```
function animate() {
    targets[index].animate({
        fill: "#cde",
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, 'linear');
    index++;
    if (index < targets.length) setTimeout(animate, 1000);
}
animate();
```

Above code shows all elements but one by one in order.

I've tried random sorting using plugin:

```
Raphael.st.sort = function (callback) {
    var cb = callback || function (a, b) {
            if (a.id < b.id) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a.id > b.id) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        };

    Array.prototype.sort(this, cb);
    this.items.sort(cb);
    return this;
};

function shuffle(a, b) {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
};
```

but without any luck.

My question is how can I randomly order collection of elements that I want to show?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/UDmym/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is working, everything happens just too fast to notice the effect.
Change the values of the animate function and watch your fiddle again.

```
function animate() {
    targets[index].animate({
        fill: "#cde",
        opacity: 1
    }, Math.floor(5000 * Math.random()), 'linear');
    index++;
    if (index < targets.length) setTimeout(animate, 1); // call doMove() very quick:-)
}
```

Comment: What I was trying to say by random order is that right now elements are showing from left to right. I want to show them randomly. Please see my updated fiddle, I removed random animation time.

Answer (score 0):

I've came with a solution, maybe there are better, but this one works for me:

```
function shuffle(a, b) {
return Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
}

var r = Raphael("holder", '100%', '100%'),
    targets = r.set(),
    tmp = [],
    size = 30,
    offset = 10;

for (var i = 0, j = 0; j < 10; i += size, j++) {
    tmp.push(r.rect(i, 10, size, size));
    i += offset;
}
tmp.sort(shuffle);

for (var i = 0, j = tmp.length; i < j; i++) {
    targets.push(tmp[i]);
}
tmp = null;

targets.attr({
    fill: "#efe",
    stroke: "#fff",
        "stroke-dasharray": "- ",
    opacity: 0.2
});
```

So basically I'm adding all rectangles to temporary array, then I randomize them and finally I add them to targets.

As I wrote this is simple solution, any other attempts are welcome!